# why moving class to shared css file in Angular increases bundle size

Tags: css, angular, bundle

This is for an Angular 11 application. I have a shared css file I'm including in several components as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-x-selector',
  templateUrl: './my-component-x.html',
  styleUrls: ['component-x.css', 'shared.css']
})
```

Adding the following test class to one of the components' css file increases
the bundle size by by 61 bytes, which matches the size of the added source snippet. But moving the class to the shared css increases the bundle size by 140 bytes. Why? It seems like Angular effectively clones the class for each component that includes the shared css file which imho severly limits, if not defeats the purpose of having shared css.

```
.tr-test00 {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 45rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ya, Imagine you has simple two components with a .css like

```
  //component-one
  template: `<h1>Hello</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { color:blue }`]

  //component-two
  template: `<h1>By</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { color:red }`]
```

Angular make an unique bundle similar to

```
h1[_ngcontent-edf-c40] {
    color: green;
}
h1[_ngcontent-edf-c41] {
  color: red;
}
```

And create an .html like

```
<hello _ngcontent-bwn-c39="">
  <h1 _ngcontent-edf-c40="">Hello</h1> //<--this is the component one
</hello>

<other_ngcontent-bwn-c42="">
   <h1 _ngcontent-edf-c41="">By</h1> //<--this is the component two
</other>
```

This makes that in component-one you see the h1 green and in component-two h1 red

When you refered a common .css to two differents components, Angular makes a bundle like

```
h1[_ngcontent-edf-c40] {
    color: green;
}
h1[_ngcontent-edf-c41] {
  color: green;
}
```

And again the .html is

```
<hello _ngcontent-bwn-c39>
   <h1 _ngcontent-edf-c40>Hello</h1> //<--this is the component one
</hello>

<other _ngcontent-bwn-c48>
   <h1 _ngcontent-edf-c41>By</h1> //<--this is the component two
</other>
```

This is the reason because the bunlde increase two times. If you want, you can take another aproach that is use a common .css and add in **your angular.json** in the way

```
.common h1{
   color:green
}
```

And enclosed yours component in a div

```
<div class="common">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

<div class="common">
    <h1>By</h1>
</div>
```

The .html it's looks like

```
   <hello _ngcontent-jxl-c46="">
      <div class="common">
         <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
   </hello>

   <other _ngcontent-jxl-c46="">
       <div class="common">
          <h1>By</h1>
       </div>
    </other>
```